# How to use google script web app with multiple pages in google site?

Tags: javascript

Here's the thing:
I have a web app that has multiple html pages in it. Code is embedded in a Google spreadsheet. 
During development I call each page by a separate doGet() function; commenting out the ones I don't want to use.
I managed to put my google sheet into the site, end embedded the Web App code for one page.
I want to put each of my html pages in different site pages.
So how do I call each html page, from the the different doGet functions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the page name through query string:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page);
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

For example, you have `Home.html` and `About.html`, you can show these pages by using:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?page=Home
https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?page=About
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but sorry, I'm not sure how this works. Is "e.parameter.page" a separate page with the different pages listed? Or is there a link to the home page that should be put on each page? Thanks for any help.

Comment: OK, finally figured most of it out. Got a home page and other pages working. Some of this stuff is more complicated than I thought. Only an Egg. Thanks to all who put code out there for us eggs.

Comment: This is actually a great idea thanks for sharing