# Is it possible to create two web apps for one Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I just started learning Google Scripts 3 days ago and was tasked to create a data entry program. I am trying to create a data entry program where inputting the data in the web app will automatically log the data inputted in the Google Spreadsheets. I have successfully created one but I need to create another one for a different type of data but I also need it to be in the same sheet.

I have tried creating my Index.html as the homepage with two buttons which should link to the other two htmls I have created but using  doesn't seem to be working as it just tells me that the file does not exist or cannot be accessed. I have looked into some references but I cannot understand some of the important parts or does not explain much.

references:
[Where I Learned Google App Scripts](https://hayykel.blogspot.com/2021/08/how-to-create-form-with-google-apps.html)

[Linking to another HTML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script)

[How to use google script web app with multiple pages in google site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394040/how-to-use-google-script-web-app-with-multiple-pages-in-google-site)

Comment: On second thought, although my answer is a perfect fit for the question, you might not need two webapps. If  don't need two end points, but just two webpages, ask a new question with your code as [mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster It was okay, it was perfectly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. One **project** can have only one `doGet` or `doPost` **function**. Therefore, in one project, you can only have one web app.  However, you can have more than one project **bound** to a spreadsheet. This used to be easy in the old editor, where you just had to go to *File > New Project*. But, with the new editor, this doesn't seem to be possible manually. You can however do it with Apps script api or a wrapper around that api, namely [clasp](/questions/tagged/clasp).

In a new folder, [create the project](https://github.com/google/clasp#create)

```
clasp create --parentId ID_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET
```

Then go to another folder and do the same command with the same parent id. If that goes well, you'll have two independent projects bound to the same spreadsheet. Now, you can have two `doGet`  and therefore have two webapps. You don't need clasp/terminal anymore, after this initial step, but it'll help a lot, if you use it though.

Comment: If I may ask for more information, what folder are you referring to or how do I make one since I cannot see an option that would allow me to do that? Also, am I supposed to install clasp first and then run the command on my terminal?

Comment: @uishauvei Yes, install clasp and do the command in any folder.

Comment: @uishauvei If you're confused, do the **codelab** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clasp/info)

Comment: thanks, I will inform you if all things go well.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now and was able to make it work. That was a great help!

Comment: @uishauvei Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark button the left of this post.